# Why is the Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature so good?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I'm taking a course in numerical methods and the Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature seems very good. I've been getting errors in the order of $10^{-16}$ for some of the problems I've been looking at. What makes this quadrature so good as compared to others?

Comment: Trefethen has a long paper analyzing the convergence of Clenshaw-Curtis: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math331.F17/Projects/GaussVsCC.pdf.

Comment: [Clenshaw–Curtis quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw%E2%80%93Curtis_quadrature)